# Python 2.7 installation from Python script

Tags: python, python-2.7, yum

I have two questions:

There is an automated python script. Initially it should install Python2.7 if already installed version is lower than 2.7. (already implemented)

1. How can i successfully and cleanly change the python interpreter without disturbing python dependencies on the system. So that the next time any python script runs, it runs with python2.7
   Linking python to python2.7 worked but it disturbs system dependencies and i cannot run modules e.g yum
2. Is there a way to continue with the remaining python script (after python2.7 installation and using python2.7 interpreter for rest of the code) without breaking the sequence or exiting the code?

Looking forwards to your responses.

Comment: You could create a virtual environment to run your code. But why do you want to use Python 2.7? Python 2 is dead (unsupported) since the beginning of 2020 and that was announced over 10 years ago.

Comment: Also, please do not tamper withthe system python installation (i's always a bad idea, the system relies on it being a specific version). Virtual environments is the right way to go

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Your best bet is to use a virtual environment. Short of that, you could try adding a ["shebang"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shebang_%28Unix%29) to the top of the Python script. The recommended shebang for specifying the "default" Python 2 interpreter is `#!/usr/bin/env python2`. Shebangs essentially allow the author of the script to specify which installation of the Python interpreter should be used when invoking this script directly (so if your script is located in script `main.py`, you would invoke it with `./main.py` as opposed to `python main.py` in order for the shebang to take effect).